# How can i Reload my UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a code in the viewDidLoad and others method, and i want to reload them if i click on a button, i already try the setNeedDisplay but it doesn't work, i don't know if i using it in the right sens?

This my code in the viewDidLoad:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      // Create the UISegmentedControler "Next Review" and "Previouse Review"
      UISegmentedControl *paginateReviewSegment  = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Précedent",@"Suivant", nil]];
      paginateReviewSegment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
      [paginateReviewSegment addTarget:self action:@selector(paginateReviews:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

       UIBarButtonItem *paginateBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:paginateReviewSegment];
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  paginateBarButton;

      [super viewDidLoad];

     // Get the review selected
      entryReview = [[entriesReview getEntries] objectAtIndex:self.reviewSelected];

    // Resize the UIScrollView
     [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.contentView.frame.size];

    // Add UIView "Content" to UIScrollView
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];

   // Set the user name
   userNameLabel.text = entryReview.userName;

   .....
   }
```

This is the action that i want to use for reloading the UIView:

```
  - (void)paginateReviews:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
  {
      if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && self.reviewSelected != 0)
      {
          self.reviewSelected -= 1; 
          entryReview = [[entriesReview getEntries] objectAtIndex:self.reviewSelected];
          [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

      } else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && self.reviewSelected != ([entriesReview entriesCount] - 1)) 
      {
          self.reviewSelected += 1; 
          entryReview = [[entriesReview getEntries] objectAtIndex:self.reviewSelected];
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` doesn't invoke the `[self viewDidLoad];`.

And, we don't call `viewDidLoad` manually. I suggest that move the code which you want to invoke into another method and invoke that method in both `viewDidLoad` and the method binding with your button.